# MiniProfilerEF view results without RenderIncludes()

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

Is there another way to view the profiling results of MiniProfiler (I'm specifically interested in EF5 version)?

Every tutorial that I've seen uses `MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes();` but since my MVC app mostly returns JSON, that is not an option for me.

Is there a way to write results to file or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read and write results to just about anywhere by changing the `MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage` to a different [`IStorage`](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage/IStorage.cs) implementation from the default (which stores to [http cache](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage/HttpRuntimeCacheStorage.cs)). If you wanted to, this could store to and read from a file pretty easily (you would have to write your own custom implementation for that).

The files served by `RenderIncludes` are the html templates for displaying the results and the script to retrieve the results from the server and render them on the client ([all found here](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/ui)). But you are by no means obliged to use this mechanism. If you want to write your own logic for retrieving and displaying results, you should base this off of the logic found in [MiniProfilerHandler.GetSingleProfilerResult](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/0767ba4e31c7f55df1b624c311b7f54a9dabeaaf/StackExchange.Profiling/MiniProfilerHandler.cs#L282). This function roughly performs the following (putting in the siginificant steps for your purposes):

1. Gets Id of next results to retrieve (through `MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage.List()`)
2. Retrieves the actual results (`MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage.Load(id)`)
3. Marks the results as viewed so that they wont be retrieved again (`MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage.SetViewed(user, id)`)
4. Converts these to `ResultsJson` and returns it

With access to `MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage`, you should be able to retrieve, serve and consume the profile results in any way that you want. And if you are interested in using the `RenderIncludes` engine but want to mess around with the html/js being served, you can provide your own [custom ui templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24010317/51) that will replace the default behavior.